# Updating a Column in Excel with values in another column

Tags: excel

I have the following list of values in one column...

```
**Column 1** - 
60                              
60
61.428571
61.428571
62.857143
62.857143
64.285714
64.285714
65.714286
65.714286
67.142857
67.142857
68.571429
68.571429
70
70
```

And then I have another two columns that were generated separately ...

```
**Column A** - 
60
62.60333676
64.04815005
64.85

**Column B** - 
65.15
65.95184995
67.39666324
70
```

Now what I would like to do is this ..

I want to replace each of the values in column 1 with values in column two sequentially .. that is the formula replaces 60 in column 1 twice (since there are two 60 values in column 1) with 60 from column A ... replaces 61.428571 twice with 62.6033 .. then replaces 62.857 twice with 64.0481.. and so on until all the values from column A have been used ..

and then for the 5th value it now switches to column B and starts replacing values in column  - so now it replaces 65.71 with 65.15 from column B until the last value in column 1 is replaced.

Any idea how this can be done with one formula>?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Formulas do not replace values in cells. You could use a formula in an unused column to the right then copy and paste the values back into the original column.

Answer (score 0):

With your original values from column 1 in D2:D17, put this formula in an unused column to the right.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$5, INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/2)+1), INDEX($B$2:$B$5, INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/2)+1-((ROW(1:1)>8)*4)))
```

Fill down as necessary. Copy those values and use Paste Special ► Values to get them back into D2:D17.

[image: Offset using maths]